# What does ~ mean in Windows user name as in "~\Administrator"?

Tags: windows-server-2016

In Server Manager, I added a remote server (both of them are not joined to a domain) and then selected "Manage As".
Typing `Administrator` or `\Administrator` in the user name field only showed an error message about the format being wrong. Then after a lot of Google search I tried `~\Administrator` and then it succeeded.

What does that `~` mean?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're mistaken. If you type `.\Administrator` it would designate local machine logon. But `~\Administrator`  would try to log you on to `~` which doesn't exist.

Comment: See this page. http://mysqlserverteam.com/windows-nano-server-technical-preview-5-and-mysql/ It uses ~\Administrator for Powershell to connect to a remote server. I think I saw this page and tried ~\Administrator on the Server Manager.

Answer (score -3):

It was first used in Windows Server 2008 and workstation Vista.

/ (forward slash) let's you know whether you are accessing Local account or Domain account.

Syntax for Domain account:-

contoso/administrator

Syntax for local admin account:-

system-1/administrator

In the above syntax 'system-1' is hostname.

Comment: Windows uses the backslash not the forwardslash in the context you've described. Also you haven't addressed the OP question regarding the tilda `~`.